# Foreign Key join in Apache Flink using DataStream API

Tags: apache-flink, streaming

Disclaimer: I am working on Apache Flink POC for my organization with various scenarios. I am in learning phase.

Currently, we are using Kafka Streams (along with KTable) for joining multiple streams. However, we are more concerned about Latency issue with Kafka Streams and that's where we are exploring option using Apache Flink.

One of the scenario involves FK join. For simplicity I am taking example of Employee and Department where employee.deptId = department.depId and Department can consists of multiple employees (one to many relationship). I am achieving this using Stateful streams as below:

```java
        //DataStreamSource<Long> streamSource = env.fromSequence(1, 10000000);
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Employee> employeeSourceStreamOperator = env
                .fromSource(employeeSource, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Employee")
                .map(value -> objectMapper.readValue(value, Employee.class));
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Department> departmentSingleOutputStreamOperator = env
                .fromSource(departmentSource, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Department")
                .map(value -> objectMapper.readValue(value, Department.class));
        employeeSourceStreamOperator
                .connect(departmentSingleOutputStreamOperator)
                .keyBy(Employee::getDeptId, Department::getDeptId)
                .map(new RichCoMapFunction<Employee, Department, Object>() {
                    // ListState to store multiple Employee instances for each department
                    private ListState<Employee> employeeListState;
                    // ValueState to store Department information
                    private ValueState<Department> departmentState;
                    @Override
                    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
                        // Initialize ListState for Employee
                        ListStateDescriptor<Employee> employeeListStateDescriptor =
                                new ListStateDescriptor<>("employeeListState", Employee.class);
                        employeeListState = getRuntimeContext().getListState(employeeListStateDescriptor);
                        // Initialize ValueState for Department
                        ValueStateDescriptor<Department> departmentStateDescriptor =
                                new ValueStateDescriptor<>("departmentState", Department.class);
                        departmentState = getRuntimeContext().getState(departmentStateDescriptor);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object map1(Employee employee) throws Exception {
                        // Process Employee stream
                        // Store Employee information in MapState based on departmentId
                        employeeListState.add(employee);
                        // Try to join with Department information
                        Department department = departmentState.value();
                        if (department != null) {
                            // Join Employee and Department information
                            return "Employee join:" + employee.getName() + " works in " + department.getDeptName();
                        }
                        return ""; // No immediate result, need to wait for Department information
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object map2(Department department) throws Exception {
                        // Process Department stream
                        // Store Department information in ValueState
                        departmentState.update(department);
                        // Try to join with Employee information
                        Iterable<Employee> employees = employeeListState.get();
                        if (employees != null) {
                            // Join Employee and Department information for each employee in the list
                            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                                result.append("Department join:" + generateOutput(employee, department)).append("\n");
                            }
                            return result.toString();
                        }
                        return ""; // No immediate result, need to wait for Employee information
                    }

                    private String generateOutput(Employee employee, Department department) {
                        return employee.getName() + " works in " + department.getDeptName();
                    }
                })
                .sinkTo(new PrintSink<>());
```

This is working as expected. However, I am not able to figure out below scenario.
Employee can change department. In this case, relation from Employee to Department can be easily changed, but removing relationship from old department is challenging. Could someone please help with Flink feature which will help me to get old department state and removing employee ?

Let me know if you need more information that is missing above?

=================================================================
Using Table API
Updated the code as per David's suggestion.

```java
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Employee> employeeSourceStreamOperator = env
                .fromSource(employeeSource, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Employee")
                .map(value -> objectMapper.readValue(value, Employee.class));
        Table employeeTable = tableEnvironment
                .fromDataStream(employeeSourceStreamOperator, $("deptId").as("empDeptId"),$("name").as("name"));

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Department> departmentSingleOutputStreamOperator = env
                .fromSource(departmentSource, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Department")
                .map(value -> objectMapper.readValue(value, Department.class));

        Table departmentTable = tableEnvironment
                .fromDataStream(departmentSingleOutputStreamOperator, Schema.newBuilder().build());

        Table table = employeeTable.join(departmentTable)
                .where($("empDeptId").isEqual($("deptId")))
                .select($("name"), $("deptName"));

        DataStream<Row> rowDataStream =
                tableEnvironment.toChangelogStream(table);
        rowDataStream.sinkTo(new PrintSink<>());
```

Published on Department 1 along with employee 6 in it as below
{"deptId":1,"deptName":"Department 1"}
5> +I[Employee 6, Department 1]

Published Employee 6 by changing deptId from 1 to 2
{"empId":6,"name":"Employee 6","deptId":2}
Employee 6 updated with Department 2
5> +I[Employee 6, Department 2]

Now Published update on Dept 1, Received below output where employee 6 is still part of department 1
5> +I[Employee 6, Department 1]

So Employee 6 is still in relation with Department 1, though Employee 6 changed the Department to 2.

I created git repo at [flink-test](https://github.com/umeshgkamat/flink-test). EmployeeDepartmentTestDataGenerator.java sample testdata tool which publishes random data on Kafka Topics.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of application is much more straightforward to implement if you use Flink's Table API (or Flink SQL). A Table/SQL join will automatically handle the update that you're concerned about. Implementing this by hand with the DataStream API is a lot of unnecessary work (it requires materializing the join in Flink state so the updates can be produced).

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Updated the question with Table API, but problem still persists. Could you please check if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Rather than adding a relationship between Employee 6 and Dept 2, you want to update Employee 6 so that they are no longer in Dept 1, but are in Dept 2 instead. This means changing the Employee table so that's an updating table rather than an append-only table (i.e.g, it needs to be based on a changelog stream that includes updates, rather than having only inserts).

Comment: Yes the relation between employee 6 and departmnet 2 updated using message published on Emploee 6 only. Only by changing employee topic. Am I not following your steps? Could you plz help updating my program if that doesnt represent? Apologies,  as i am still in learning phase.

Comment: If the employee table is backed by a compacted Kafka topic using the upsert-kafka connector and defines empDeptId as the primary key, then I believe it will work.